# c# how to solve a issue using substring

Tags: c#, substring

How to solve substring issue. I have tried to code correctly but not working for me.

The file name is bad_filename.xml or good_filename.xml

what i want is to use substring to result "bad" or "good" where _filename.xml should be removed. how to do this?

From: bad_filename.xml or good_filename.xml

to: bad or good

Comment: `str.Replace("bad","good")`

Comment: spilt with '_' and get first object

Comment: dont want to replace it. need to read file name and remove the rest to result bad or good

Comment: `str =str.Replace("_filename.xml","")`

Comment: What should happen if the input is `"somerandomfilename.xml"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, as I have mention in Question comment.

```
var result = filename.Split('_')[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  string s = "bad_filename.xml";
  string sub = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("_"));
  string sub2 = string.Concat((s.TakeWhile(x => x != '_')));
  string sub3 = s.Split('_')[0];
```

I've given three ways pick any one of your choice

Note: Way (1) will throw exception when string doesn't contain `_` you need to check index > `-1`

Comment: Downvotes to be given for wrong answers not with `Hard feelings`. I don't think this answer is wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = filename.Split('_')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) class to get the file name and [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get the first part:

```
string fileNameWOE = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("bad_filename.xml");
string firstPart = fileNameWOE.Split('_')[0];
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Of course, but it's always better to use the methods from `Path` if you're fiddling around with paths or filenames. Maybe this is just a simplified example and the filename actually contains the full path or maybe it will in future.

Comment: Of course I agree with you but IMO isn't it redundant here? If Op asked for right side part of string after `_` it is required. and we definitely need it.

Comment: Extracting parts of a path (or creating paths) with string methods is the wrong tool for the job, in general. So even if it works now it is less readable and more error-prone than using methods from `Path` and it might break your code in future. So there is absolutely no reason to avoid `Path`.

Comment: Isn't the whole argument irrelevant? How do we know that the OP isn't already using the methods found in `Path`? He hasn't posted any code, he has simply stated that he has a filename that he needs to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string input = "bad_filename.xml"   
string sub = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf("_"));
Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", sub);
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this :

```
string[] strArr = stringFileName.Split('_');

string[] strArr = bad_filename.xml.Split('_');
strArr[0] is "bad"
and
string[] strArr = good_filename.xml.Split('_');
strArr[0] is "good"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for substring.

```
   string a="bad_filename.xml ";
            int index=a.IndexOf('_');
            if (index != -1)
            {
                string filename = a.Substring(0,index);
            }
```

output is bad